# How to insert a value into a sorted Vector in a single pass?

Tags: performance, haskell, vector, fusion

I have a [`Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector.html#t:Vector) of sorted values, for example

```
fromList [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Now I'd like to insert another value, let's say `3` and create a new vector. In an imperative language I'd allocate an array of size 5, loop over the original vector, copy the old values, and insert the new one at the proper point, so that I obtain

```
fromList [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I can do it using *vector* API as

```
let (pre, post) = span (< x) n
in V.concat [pre, pure x, post]
```

which works, but traverses the original vector twice: Once when searching for the split and once when combining it. Is there a way how to do it in just one  pass? (Another solution would be to search for the splitting point using a binary search, but I'm interested if it's possible to create a genuine single-pass solution.)

Comment: I note that you have neither accepted nor commented on either of the existing answers. Is there something in particular that makes them unsatisfactory, or do you just want to see if someone comes up with a better one?

Comment: @dfeuer I just haven't had enough time to study the solutions properly.

Comment: That's fair! Seriously, if you have any questions about mine, I will be very happy to answer them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[user5402's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28659740/1477667) is quite a pretty way to do it, but it falls prey to an efficiency problem described in the `Data.Vector` [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector.html#g:5). Specifically, once it has found the insertion spot, and is copying blindly, it no longer forces the values to actually be read from the source vector. Instead, it fills up the destination vector with thunks that, when forced, read from the source vector.

#### Original solution

Note: This is the first solution I came up with. It is pretty easy to understand, but it does not play well with the stream fusion system in `vector`, which can lead to relatively poor performance. The solutions below are better in general.

One solution, as explained in the documentation, is to use the monadic `indexM` operation to perform these blind reads. This forces the read to be performed, but does not force the read value. Thus it copies a pointer (possibly a pointer to a thunk) from the source vector to the destination vector. For greatest efficiency, everything below should be replaced with its `unsafe` variant (`unsafeIndexM`, `unsafeIndex`, and `unsafeWrite` in particular).

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Insert where
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import Data.Vector.Mutable (MVector)
import Control.Monad.ST

insertElem :: forall a . Ord a => a -> Vector a -> Vector a
insertElem e v = V.create act
 where
  act :: forall s . ST s (MVector s a)
  act = do
    mv <- MV.new (V.length v + 1)
    let
      start :: Int -> ST s (MVector s a)
      start i
        | i == V.length v ||
          e <= v V.! i = MV.write mv i e >> finish i
        | otherwise = MV.write mv i (v V.! i) >> start (i+1)
      finish :: Int -> ST s (MVector s a)
      finish i
        | i == V.length v = return mv
        | otherwise = do
             V.indexM v i >>= MV.write mv (i+1)
             finish (i+1)
      in start 0

insertElemInt :: Int -> Vector Int -> Vector Int
insertElemInt = insertElem
```

Note that naming the `act` action and using `ScopedTypeVariables` should not actually be necessary, but I found them tremendously helpful in tracking down my mistakes.

### Stream-based solutions

The above code won't work well with stream fusion, because indices fly all over the place. The following approach should fuse properly, and still avoid creating unnecessary thunks. This is the first time I've ever touched stream fusion code, so it may be that some things could be improved. The only problem with this first stream-based version is that if it *does* fuse, then the step function for the input stream will be run twice on one of the elements. This is normally not a problem, but if the step function is extremely expensive (rare), it could be. I therefore give an alternative that should work better in that case. I'm not sure just when which of these will be better in practice, so I'm including both.

With either of these stream-based solutions, the code

```
testEnum :: Word -> Word -> Word -> Word
testEnum ins low high = V.product $
  insertElem ins $ V.enumFromStepN low 1 (fromIntegral high)
```

will compile into loops that run in constant space, never actually creating a vector at all.

#### Step one seed twice

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Insert where

import Data.Vector (Vector)
import Data.Word (Word)
import qualified Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic as S
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import Data.Vector.Fusion.Util (Id(..))

-- To check on unboxing and such
insertElemWord :: Word -> Vector Word -> Vector Word
insertElemWord = insertElem

{-# INLINE insertElem #-}
insertElem :: forall a . Ord a => a -> Vector a -> Vector a
insertElem a v = G.unstream (insertElemS a (G.stream v))

{-# INLINE [1] insertElemS #-}
insertElemS :: forall a . Ord a => a -> S.Stream Id a -> S.Stream Id a
insertElemS e (S.Stream step (state::s) size) = S.Stream step' (state, False) (size + 1)
  where
    {-# INLINE [0] step' #-}
    step' :: (s, Bool) -> Id (S.Step (s, Bool) a)
    step' (s, True) = Id $ case unId (step s) of
       S.Yield a s' -> S.Yield a (s', True)
       S.Skip s' -> S.Skip (s', True)
       S.Done -> S.Done
    step' (s, False) = Id $ case unId (step s) of
       S.Yield a s' ->
          if e <= a
          then S.Yield e (s, True)
          else S.Yield a (s', False)
       S.Skip s' -> S.Skip (s', False)
       S.Done -> S.Yield e (s, True)
```

#### One pass exactly, never repeating a lookup/step

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Insert where

import Data.Vector (Vector)
import Data.Word (Word)
import qualified Data.Vector.Fusion.Stream.Monadic as S
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import Data.Vector.Fusion.Util (Id(..))

data Status s a = Pre s | During s a | Post s | End

insertElemWord :: Word -> Vector Word -> Vector Word
insertElemWord = insertElem

{-# INLINE insertElem #-}
insertElem :: forall a . Ord a => a -> Vector a -> Vector a
insertElem a v = G.unstream (insertElemS a (G.stream v))

{-# INLINE [1] insertElemS #-}
insertElemS :: forall a . Ord a => a -> S.Stream Id a -> S.Stream Id a
insertElemS e (S.Stream step (state::s) size) = S.Stream step' (Pre state) (size+1)
  where
    {-# INLINE [0] step' #-}
    step' :: Status s a -> Id (S.Step (Status s a) a)
    step' (Post s) = Id $ case unId (step s) of
      S.Yield a s' -> S.Yield a (Post s')
      S.Skip s' -> S.Skip (Post s')
      S.Done -> S.Done
    step' (Pre s) = Id $ case unId (step s) of
      S.Yield a s'
        | e <= a    -> S.Yield e (During s' a)
        | otherwise -> S.Yield a (Pre s')
      S.Skip s' -> S.Skip (Pre s')
      S.Done -> S.Yield e End
    step' (During s a) = Id (S.Yield a (Post s))
    step' End = Id S.Done
```

Comment: Note: this solution works for the version of `vector` that shipped with GHC 7.8.  Things have changed a bit in the latest version, necessitating some (fairly minor) changes. If you need details, I can give them.

Comment: Could you please explain why it's needed to give stages `[1]` and `[0]` to `INLINE` in this case?

Comment: @PetrPudlák, I'm not really sure, but that seems to be the way it's generally done in `vector`. It surely has something to do with the timing of the various rewrite rules.

Answer (score 3):

The best tool that seems to be available is `unfoldr`, e.g.:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector (Vector)

insertElem :: Int -> Vector Int -> Vector Int
insertElem e v = V.unfoldrN (len+1) go (0,False)
  where
    len = V.length v
    go (i,found)
      | i >= len  = if found then Nothing else Just (e, (i+1, True))
      | found     = Just (x, (i+1, True))
      | x <= e    = Just (x, (i+1, False))
      | otherwise = Just (e, (i, True))
      where x = v V.! i


test1 = insertElem 3 (V.fromList [1,2,4,5])
test2 = insertElem 0 (V.fromList [1,2,4,5])
test3 = insertElem 6 (V.fromList [1,2,4,5])
```

I didn't try very hard to de-dup the logic in the `go` function.